# CATextLayer shows its content only after a while

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, core-graphics, cashapelayer

I know that it sounds weird, but the problem is precisely that: I have a `ViewController` that loads a CSV file async with Grand Central Dispatch (the file represents an histogram). I have also a custom view called `HistogramView`. When the controller finishes loading CSV file, it calls a function `invalidate` on the `HistogramView`. In that function, the view parses the data read from the file and creates:

1. some CAShapeLayer that represent the bars of the histogram
2. some CATextLayer that represent the labels for the bars

For the shape layers no problem, all works great. The problem occurs with the text layers: only the background is shown, initially. The text appears only after some seconds :-/ and this is very strange. This is the code of the `invalidate` function (this function, as I said, is in the custom view).

```
-(void)invalidate{
    float tempX = 0;
    float tempHeight = 0;
    NSArray *data;

    if([self.dataSource getHistogramData] != nil){
        data = [self.dataSource getHistogramData];
        tempX = [self getStartingX];
        [self getDataMaxValue];

        for (int i=0; i<[data count]; i+=2) {

            //THE SHAPE LAYER THAT REPRESENTS AN HISTOGRAM BAR
            tempHeight = [self uniformValue:[[data objectAtIndex:i+1] intValue]];
            CAShapeLayer *rectLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(tempX, tempHeight, barWidth, height - tempHeight - spaceForLabels);
            rectLayer.path = CGPathCreateWithRect(rect, nil);
            [rectLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1].CGColor];
            [self.layer addSublayer:rectLayer];


            //THE TEXT LAYER THAT REPRESENTS A LABEL FOR THE BAR
            CATextLayer *textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
            textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(tempX, height - spaceForLabels, barWidth, spaceForLabels);
            textLayer.font = CFBridgingRetain([UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18].fontName);
            textLayer.fontSize = 18;
            textLayer.foregroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
            textLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
            textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
            textLayer.string = @"example";
            [self.layer addSublayer:textLayer];


            tempX += barWidth + spaceBetweenBars;
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see I create the bars and the labels in the same way and at the same point. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** in my view controller I do the work within `viewDidLoad` method this way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //create the channel with which read the CSV file
    dispatch_io_t ch = dispatch_io_create_with_path(DISPATCH_IO_STREAM, [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"histogram1" ofType:@"csv"] UTF8String], O_RDONLY, 0, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), nil);

    //read the CSV file async with GCD
    [self readCSVFile:ch];

    //set the delegates for the histogram view
    self.histogramView.delegate = self;
    self.histogramView.dataSource = self;
}

-(void)readCSVFile:(dispatch_io_t)ch{

    //the string that represents the content of CSV file
    NSMutableString __block *stringFromData;

    //read the whole file
    dispatch_io_read(ch, 0, SIZE_MAX, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(bool done, dispatch_data_t dataRead, int error) {

        if(!error && !done){

            //convert from dispatch_data_t to NSString
            size_t dataSize = dispatch_data_get_size(dataRead);
            stringFromData = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithCapacity:dataSize];
            dispatch_data_apply(dataRead, ^bool(dispatch_data_t region, size_t offset, const void *buffer, size_t size) {
                [stringFromData appendFormat:@"%.*s", (unsigned int)size, buffer];
                return true;
            });
        }else{
            dispatch_io_close(ch, 0);
            data = [stringFromData componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                       [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n,"]];

            //AND NOW I CALL INVALIDATE ON THE VIEW
            [self.histogramView invalidate];
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Is invalidate being called on the main thread?

Comment: Mmh... actually no. Because the data that I pass to the View are loaded from an async file read (thanks to Grand Central Dispatch). I call 'invalidate' from within the code block executed at the end of the dispatch_io_read. Check my EDIT. Is that a problem? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I get it. I'd like to thank **rdelmar** that with his suggestion points me to the problem. As he said, `invalidate` isn't being called from the main thread, but from a background thread (the thread that reads the file). This is wrong because the View has to be updated from the main thread. So, I solve the issue simply calling the `invalidate` method this way:

```
-(void)readCSVFile:(dispatch_io_t)ch{

    //the string that represents the content of CSV file
    NSMutableString __block *stringFromData;

    //read the whole file
    dispatch_io_read(ch, 0, SIZE_MAX, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(bool done, dispatch_data_t dataRead, int error) {

        if(!error && !done){

            //convert from dispatch_data_t to NSString
            size_t dataSize = dispatch_data_get_size(dataRead);
            stringFromData = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithCapacity:dataSize];
            dispatch_data_apply(dataRead, ^bool(dispatch_data_t region, size_t offset, const void *buffer, size_t size) {
                [stringFromData appendFormat:@"%.*s", (unsigned int)size, buffer];
                return true;
            });
        }else{
            dispatch_io_close(ch, 0);
            data = [stringFromData componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                       [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n,"]];

            //HERE IS THE SOLUTION
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]addOperationWithBlock:^{
                [self.histogramView invalidate];
            }];
        }

    });
}
```